# Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging

I have the following problem when I debug this code:

```
// Croppen.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h" 

int i,j,c;
char hex[] = {"header.hex"},
     ziel[] = {"ergebniss.bmp"},
     eingabe[100];
FILE *f,*h;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {//eingabe des Orginalen Bildnamens
        printf("Bitte geben sie den Bild namen ein. Maxiaml 20 Zeichen, mit '.bmp'\n");

        do { scanf("%s", eingabe); } while ( getchar() != '\n' );

        if ((f = fopen(eingabe,"rb")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Fehler beim Öffnen von %s\n",eingabe);
            system("exit");
        }
    }

    {//header einlesen
        h = fopen(hex,"wb");
        for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) { putc(getc(f),h); }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces this error:

```
'Croppen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The program '[2884] Croppen.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Can any one say where my problem is?

I use the MS VS 2010 Prof IDE.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using C-style strings and C-style functions such as `fopen`?

Comment: What is `system("exit")`?

Comment: yes, its a promam with ca 2000 open, close other E/A commandos an i dont want to change them if possible. system("exit"); comes vome the good old DOS it easyly close the programm

Comment: It doesn't, you must use exit() instead.  Exit codes tend to match operating system error codes on an abnormal exit, 3 = "path not found".  Plenty of coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do {
    scanf("%s", eingabe);
} while ( getchar() != '\n');
```

isn't a lucky choice for reading from file word by word. You could either do (C-style approach):

```
while (scanf("%s", eingabe) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

or use `std::string`s and streams instead (C++):

```
std::string word;
while (std::cin >> word) {
    ...
}
```

although I think you just want to read 1 line with a filename in this case:

```
std::string filename;
if (std::getline(std::cin, filename)) {
    ...
}
```